# is there any spring chained transaction manager alternative?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a method that saves details to two different repositories, each belonging to a separate database:

```
public void method() {
   Repository1.saveDetails(CategoryList);
   Repository2.saveDetails(CategoryList);
}
```

Until now, I have been using the chained transaction manager to ensure that the transaction is atomic across both repositories. However, I learned that the chained transaction manager is deprecated, and I am looking for an alternative solution.

Is there a recommended alternative to the chained transaction manager that I can use to ensure that the transaction is atomic across both repositories?"

Comment: The chained transactionmanager isn't atomic, it does a best effort but if repo1 succeeds and repo2 fails there is no way of rolling back repo1. If you want really atomic (or better atomic transactions) you will need to use XA transactions which can span multiple resources.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you point to some resources where i can learn more about this?